# Brightness Fn keys not working

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, brightness

I can't increase/decrease screen brightness with Fn-keys. This is a Lenovo Thinkpad L15. OS is xubuntu 22.04.
-The rest of Fn-keys work ok (e.g. volume up/down).
-Brightness slider in Power Manager works ok.
-Even when brightness Fn-keys are pressed the corresponding pop-up shows up. But no changes increasing in its progress bar, nor in real brightness.
-Can't remember well, but I'm pretty sure it worked ok after installing xubuntu, and problem started after some time (update maybe).

I'm really new with gnu/linux, please let me know how to get/put here meaningful info in order to get help from you.

Thanx in advance, and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

In Power Manager settings -> "Handle display brightness keys" was off.

Thank you anyways.